# Joining 3 tables with no relation between first and third

Tags: mysql

I want to join three tables

1. patient_data  - (p.name)
2. employer_data - (e.name , e.city , e.stateAB)
3. list_option_data - (l.state)

`patient_data` and `employer_data` have common field `pid`
`employer_data` and `list_option_data` have comon field `stateAB`

So I want to display `p.name, e.name, e.city, l.state`:

```
select
    p.name,
    e.name,
    e.city,
    l.state
from patient_data as p
inner join
 /*
    this part i need to know how to join these...
 */
```

Comment: :):) I tried the below one before posting the question. but some problem with sp then, I was not getting the value in my apln.So I guess I may missed something.. Now I have to sit back and check where my exact error is.. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You code it much like you have explained it:

```
select
    p.name,
    e.name,
    e.city,
    l.state
from patient_data p
join employer_data e on e.pid = p.pid
join list_option_data l on l.stateAB = e.stateAB
```

Note that the `inner` of `inner join` is redundant - the default join type is `inner`